# React JS change class with transition

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm building a website with ReactJS. On my page, I have a content section as well as a sidebar.

When I click on a button the sidebar should be toggled. At this moment, I'm changing the class of the content from `col-md-9` to `col-md-12` from bootstrap and set the attribute `hidden` to the sidebar.

But now, I want to add some transitions like fade in and fade out the sidebar and increase the size of the content. I have no idea how I can add these transitions because I'm changing the classes.

Can you tell me what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS. Take a look at animate.css

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: This doesn't hep me. I need to create a transition on if a class change or something like this. Your framework only supports some default transitions

Answer (score 0):

You can use css transition by changing classes. Here is example of two clsses that will do fade animation:

```
.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
}


.fade-out {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 400ms;
}
```

However it wouldn't work along with `hidden` Bootstrap class name, because it sets `display` attribute to `none` value. TO make it work you can use `fade-in` class name instead of `hidden` and `fade-out`, when side nav should become visible